# Don't want to sort parameter in sort sequence alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, sorting, request, alamofire

Here is my request of my api

http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Service/GetEntry.aspx?FromDate=01/08/2018&RID=1&ToDate=25/10/2018&TokenID=1e731b96-4261-453b-848c-5b1a0d44f808

But my original request is like 
http://xxxxxxxxxxxxx/Service1/GetEntry.aspx?TokenID=5edc678f-82ee-4cf8-956e-5f1d3798dfec&RID=1&FromDate=01%2F08%2F2018&ToDate=25%2F10%2F2018

Here are my request param and api call

```
        var param = [String:Any]()
        param["TokenID"] = tokenId
        param["RID"] = Rid
        param["FromDate"] = DateUtilities.convertStringfromDate(date: DateUtilities.getDateofMonthStartOfLast2Month())
        param["ToDate"] = DateUtilities.convertStringfromDate(date: Date())

        print(param)

        // Network request
        Alamofire.request(finalURL, method: .post, parameters: param, encoding: URLEncoding.queryString, headers: headers).responseJSON { (response: DataResponse<Any>) in

        // check result is success
        guard response.result.isSuccess else {
            failure((response.result.error?.localizedDescription)!,"100")
            return
        }

        if let arrResponse = response.result.value as? [[String: Any]]{
            // get status code
            if arrResponse[0]["Status"] as? String ?? "" == "Error"{

                let statusCode = arrResponse[0][Constants.ResponseKey.code] as? String ?? "0"

                if statusCode == "8"{
                    //Call logout api
                    ApplicationData.sharedInstance.logoutUser()
                    return
                }
                // get status message
                let message = arrResponse[0][Constants.ResponseKey.message] as? String ?? ""

                failure(message,statusCode)
                return
            }

            success(arrResponse, "")
            return

        }
    }
```

But due to sequence mismatch I do not get as per desired response, I am getting error in api response.Here I think it is problem of alamofire which taking parameters in sorting into querystring. How can I avoid sorting in request?

Please help me with it.

Comment: Dictionary can not be sorted . !! If you are sending proper parameter it is your backhand guy responsibility to catch the value from query string.

Comment: That's the problem, I don't know backend guy so I have to send same request as per I described above.

Comment: I wonder  why your backhand guy need query string in order !! .  Communicate with him. and it is very bad practice to send everything in query string including token !!

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya what is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is a closed issue on Alamofire already Follow this [link](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/2342).

> Unfortunately Swift's dictionaries aren't order preserving, so there's
>   no way to currently accomplish this.
>
> Alamofire currently encodes URL parameters in alphabetical order, but
>   there's no way to preserve an arbitrary ordering in the dictionary. So
>   unless the order is want is a sort of some kind, or the arbitrary
>   ordering of the dictionary.

Comment: It would be best to include the suggested solution from that Alamofire issue, as well as the explanation. Essentially, if you want to preserve parameter order, you'll need to do your own parameter encoding.